# Refresh rate of background windows

Tags: screen-capture, window-manager

When recording a window in macOS Big Sur (with share screen in Zoom or in OBS) the window will go into "background mode" and start to refresh extremely slowly if it's completely obscured by another window. Is there any way to force macOS to repaint a window even though it's "hidden" behind another window?

I have found that leaving just the tiniest sliver of the window visible makes the window refresh as normal. But it would be helpful not having to micromanage the position of my windows.

Comment: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217316/how-to-create-a-video-recording-of-a-background-window?rq=1) gives some detail about the reasons why macOS cannot render background (obscured) windows.